# Restrict of updating opportunity owner

Tags: apex, trigger, validation-rule

I want to restrict updating the opportunity owner. I'm not able to use the validation rule because `ISCHANGED( Owner.Id )` is not working. It's giving the following error, **Error: The ISCHANGED function cannot reference the Owner.Id field.**

When I use `ISCHANGED( OwnerId ) validation is not working.
Below is my code

```
AND(  Region_of_Opportunity__c == 'US',
      Region_of_Opportunity__c == 'CANADA',
      Record_Type_Name__c != 'Advisors',
      Record_Type_Name__c != 'APT',
      Record_Type_Name__c != 'Vocalink',
      Record_Type_Name__c != 'Enterprise Partnership', 
      Record_Type_Name__c != 'Advisors - New Opportunity',
      ISCHANGED( OwnerId )      
)
```

Please help me !!!

Comment: Is it possible for the Opportunity have a 'Region_of_Opportunity__c' value of US & Canada at the same time? Owner.Id will never work as you cannot cross-reference objects using *IsChanged()*.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have two issues here.

1. Understanding of how to use isChanged()
2. Understanding conditional logic in validation rules

**isChanged()**

You are unable to cross-reference objects using this check. As you are on the Opportunity object, Owner.Id is an attempt to reference the User object. You must use OwnerId which is a lookup to the User object.

**Conditional logic in validation rules**

```
AND(  Region_of_Opportunity__c == 'US',
      Region_of_Opportunity__c == 'CANADA',
      Record_Type_Name__c != 'Advisors',
      Record_Type_Name__c != 'APT',
      Record_Type_Name__c != 'Vocalink',
      Record_Type_Name__c != 'Enterprise Partnership', 
      Record_Type_Name__c != 'Advisors - New Opportunity',
      ISCHANGED( OwnerId )      
)
```

The above formula will never prevent the User from changing the Owner of Opportunity unless **all** conditions are met, which I believe is incorrect. You must use an OR condition within your AND.

```
AND(
    OR( Region_of_Opportunity__c == 'US',
        Region_of_Opportunity__c == 'CANADA'
    ),
    AND (
        OR( Record_Type_Name__c != 'Advisors',
            Record_Type_Name__c != 'APT',
            Record_Type_Name__c != 'Vocalink',
            Record_Type_Name__c != 'Enterprise Partnership', 
            Record_Type_Name__c != 'Advisors - New Opportunity'
        )
    ), ISCHANGED( OwnerId )      
)
```

Answer (score 0):

a Similar validation worked for me. The only extra check I added was the **NOT(ISNEW())**. You could try adding that.

AND(
NOT(ISNEW()), 
ISPICKVAL(LeadSource, 'Partner Referral'), 
ISCHANGED(OwnerId) 
)

Answer (score 0):

Try the following formula -

```
AND(  
  OR(
      Region_of_Opportunity__c == 'US',
      Region_of_Opportunity__c == 'CANADA'
  ),
  OR(
      Record_Type_Name__c != 'Advisors',
      Record_Type_Name__c != 'APT',
      Record_Type_Name__c != 'Vocalink',
      Record_Type_Name__c != 'Enterprise Partnership', 
      Record_Type_Name__c != 'Advisors - New Opportunity'
  ),
  NOT(ISNEW()),
  ISCHANGED( OwnerId )
```

)

Comment: Hi Naval, I must use  use an OR condition within AND.